# Advantage of static_cast<void*>() to see the memory address?

Tags: c++, casting, malloc, alignment

In the cppreference below there are usages of `static_cast` to cast `int*` to `void*`,
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc
.
What the program on the URL does is first declaring two pointers (`p1` and `p2` of `int*`) and then dynamically allocating the memory using either `malloc` or `aligned_alloc`.
To see the memory alignment, it also shows the addresses of allocated memory.
This is ok for now.

However, there exist `static_cast<void*>(p1)` and `static_cast<void*>(p2)` to show the memory addresses.
Why are those cast needed?
I confirmed that without this casting, `p1` and `p2` themselves show the memory addresses (probably aligned or unaligned, depending on use of malloc or alligned_alloc).
For each pointer, an address shown is not different regardless of use of the casting...